# In angular bootstrap4.3 class not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 7 version and I have updated my bootstrap version from 3.7 to 4.3.
In bootstrap 3.7 below code is working but in boostrap 4.3 the code is not working properly in angular.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <app-select>
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">div one </div>
         </app-select>
         <app-select>
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-success">div two</div>
         </app-select>
         <app-select>
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">div three</div>
         </app-select>         
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<app-select></app-select>` html code to specify the problem but as far as I understood about your code the problem is row and col not being used nested to each other for example you should do something like:

```
<div class="container">
     <app-select>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">div one </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-success">div two</div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">div three</div>
         </div>
     </app-select>
</div>
```